# Node.js: [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, discord.js, fs

I'm trying to make a discord bot that saves images sent to it into a folder, and I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined.
```

This is my code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const client = new Discord.Client();

var prefix = "."

client.on("ready", () => {
  client.user.setStatus('online');
  console.log("Bot is on.")
});

client.on("message", message => {
  console.log(__dirname)
  var image = message.attachments.first()
  fs.writeFileSync(`./${image.name}`, image.file);
})

client.login(process.env.token);
```

Note: I'm using Discord.js v12.5.3

Comment: It looks like the file is not sent with the [attachment](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Attachment) but you should be able to download it from the `url`

Comment: what do you mean, i only sent the image

Comment: try `console.log( message.attachments.first() )` and examine the output. It looks like the object isn't as you expect.

Comment: i got [object Object]

Comment: @Gavin please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no file property on [`attachments`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v12/class/MessageAttachment). There is a [`url`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v12/class/MessageAttachment?scrollTo=url) property though from where you can download the image. You can use [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) to fetch the file (you'll need to install it by running `npm i node-fetch@2` in your command line). Once the file is fetched, you can use `fs.writeFileSync()`.

The following code works fine:

```js
// using discord.js v12
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const fs = require('fs');

const client = new Client();
const prefix = '.';

client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  const image = message.attachments.first();

  if (!image)
    return console.log('No attached image found');

  // add more if needed
  const imageFiles = ['image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/webp'];

  if (!imageFiles.includes(image.contentType))
    return console.log('Not an image file');

  try {
    const res = await fetch(image.url);
    const buffer = await res.buffer();

    fs.writeFileSync(`./${image.name}`, buffer);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Error reading/writing image file:`, error);
  }
});
```